# Error using cx_Freeze to turn .py in .exe

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

i have a program in python that i'd like to turn to .exe using cx_Freeze, but it gives an error, follow the image:
[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guiw6.png)

Here's my setup.py code

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
import os.path
from tkinter import *


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 
'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
        ],
   },
}

base=None

if sys.platform=='win32':
   base='Win32GUI'

executables=[
   Executable('TABUADATKINTER.py',base=base)
]

buildOptions=dict(
   packages=[],
   includes=['pygame'],
   include_files=[],
   excludes=[]
)

setup(
   name='Tabuada',
   version='1.0',
   description='TABUADA',
   options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
   executables=executables
)
```

Tell me if the code of my program is needed,
please help me, i don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
import os.path
from tkinter import *


PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

packages = ["pygame"]

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
        ],

        'packages':packages,
   },
}

base=None

if sys.platform=='win32':
   base='Win32GUI'

executables=[Executable('TABUADATKINTER.py',base=base)]

setup(
    name = 'Tabuada',
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'TABUADA',
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: I tried this, I built the program at the console and the executable was generated inside a folder full of archives, when I clicked it and gave me the following error: [link](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/erro1-png--45)

Comment: Well the good news it means you've gotten further because before it was erroring out at line 1 and now it's line 11. Could you share that section of your code?

Comment: I did it!! The problem was with the command that changes the form icon, the comand was `win.iconbitmap('cubic.ico')`, i took this off from the code, and ran the command to build the program in the console, and it worked, now i will just use another program to change the icon, thanks for the help!!

Comment: Good to hear :)